# Hive not querying data stored in hdfs by flume

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-sandbox

I am doing a Big Data project and have created an external table in Hive that should query data stored in HDFS. Data is streamed into HDFS using Flume. However I am getting errors when I query the data stored in HDFS. All the permissions seem to be OK. The permissions to the stored data in HDFS are `-rw-r--r--`

The table created is below:

```
create external table recommendation.bets (
 betId int,
 odds decimal,
 selectionID String,
 eventID String,
 match String,
 categoryID int,
 subCategoryID String,
 leagueName String,
 parentSubCategory String,
 marketID String,
 preMatchBet String,
 name String,
 matchOdds decimal,
 stake decimal,
 mobile boolean,
 providerName String,
 totalOdds decimal,
 totalStake decimal,
 nation String,
 `betDate` Date,
 currency String,
 calendarDate String)
 row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
 location 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/archiving/bets';
```

I have spent multiple hours searching for this case with no luck. The error log being generated is the following:

```
{"message":"H170 Unable to fetch results. java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException [ERROR_STATUS]","status":500,"trace":"org.apache.ambari.view.hive.client.HiveErrorStatusException: H170 Unable to fetch results. java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException [ERROR_STATUS]\n\norg.apache.ambari.view.hive.client.HiveErrorStatusException: H170 Unable to fetch results. java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException [ERROR_STATUS]\n\tat
```

I only pasted the beginning of the error log as it generates a huge log. I would gladly appreciate any help and guidance on what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the error occur when Flume is running? Does it occur when Flume is stopped? How do you persist the Flume data (e.g. rolling appender with a temp name that is ignored by Hive)?

Comment: Does the error occur only in Ambari interface, or also with `beeline` thin- and `hive` fat-client on command line?

Comment: Why did you insert that case-sensitive `\`betDate\`` column while all other column names are case-insensitive?

Comment: Prior to setting betData as case-sensitive it was giving me errors. Than it worked

Comment: BTW, are you really sure that these `decimal` columns (i.e. `decimal(10,0)` by default since Hive 0.13) are appropriate for your data?

Comment: This dataset actually worked minus the preMatchBet and marketID...I than added them and recreated the database and table and did not work.